# how to use Qt to accomplish "recent projects" function

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt to do a program .and now i want to implement "recent projects" function just like visual studio's recent projects function . MFC use MRU to accomplish this function ,but how to use QT to accomplish this function?

Comment: Store the IDs/paths etc. in a QStringList, persist it in QSettings, use a QMenu to display it. Or what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for your advise !  it works!